# Reference UI depending on selected feature in a Windows Installer

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer

In my installer, the first two screens are always the same (a welcome dialog and a feature choice with check boxes). Each feature requires different dialogs, with a couple in common.

I was wondering if it was possible to have a UI element for each feature, and depending on what the user chose as their wanted features, reference the correct UI.

I want to just set a property, such as `FEATURETOINSTALL`, on exiting my feature choice dialog corresponding to the Id of the UI I want.

```
<UI Id="CommonUI">
    ...
</UI>
<Property Id="FEATURETOINSTALL" Value="DefaultUIId"/>
<UIRef Id="[FEATURETOINSTALL]"/>
```

Basically, I want to reference a UI element when there's already UI shown on the machine.

Is there a way to dynamically reference a UI element when there's UI already being shown, instead of doing it manually with a bunch of `Publish` tags?

Comment: You could use ADDLOCAL property to get the list of selected to be installed features, no need to build it manually.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367536(v=vs.85).aspx 

Regarding the UI element, I don't know if that is possible or not.

Comment: @BogdanMitrache I use the AddLocal and Remove events depending on the checkboxes. I was just wondering if I had to make a `Publish` tag for each feature on the next button to send the user to the right dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The Id's and Ref's are build (compile/link) time concepts and must be fully resolved when building the MSI. For runtime manipulations you'll need to manipulate the `Publish` conditions.